# What is a student process?

Tags: terminology, operating-systems, process-scheduling, os-kernel, multi-tasking

According to [Galvin and Silberschatz](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=WjvX0HmVTlMC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA163#v=onepage&q&f=false), 5 queues are maintained in multilevel queue scheduling, each for:

- System Process
- Interactive Process
- Interactive Editing Process
- Batch process
- Student Process

where System process has highest priority and Student process has lowest priority.

What is meant by **Student Process**?

Also, I only have a vague idea about the rest except system process. If possible, elucidate them.

Comment: I don't know how we can possibly answer this question.  You haven't given us enough context.  Where did you get that list of queues from?  What information is available about them?  At present, you're asking us to guess what "student process" means without any context, and that's not reasonable.  Please provide all relevant context in the question, and where that list came from, and what you've already tried on your own.

Comment: @D.W. See [Galvin and Silberschatz, OS Concepts](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/undergraduate/421/spring03/slides/ch6-2.pdf) *(page no 12 in the link)* . *('Galvin and Silberschatz' is the most famous on Operating Systems)*

Comment: What context did Galvin & Silberschatz provide?  Questions should be self-contained, so people don't need to read some other resource to understand all of the relevant context.  Also, please edit the question to include all relevant information in the question (comments exist only to help you improve the question).  Thank you!

Comment: @D.W. updated. Hope this will meet your expectation. BTW, it is not a question in the book. They are simply saying that there are 5 queues, as stated in the OP, but I did not understand what a student process is. Thank You

Comment: Unfortunately, the slides still don't provide enough context to answer the question -- this is part of the reason why reading somebody's Powerpoint just isn't a good way to learn. Unlike the other classes of process mentioned, "student process" isn't a standard term in operating systems so it must be something that's either explained in the book or explained by something that was said during the presentation. (Having said that, I agree with babou's guess.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby OK sir, I have changed the link, you can read the page on the book itself. I think, system  processes are , well, **System** processes, Interactive Processes are those which need user interaction, eg a browser; Interactive Editing Process are like gedit, and Batch process are more or less scripts. But I have no idea what a student process is. May be they are the processes initiated by another process. Babou's answer says student proccess's priority can be increased, but by definition, they have lowest priority. And I also don't think student here literally means a student.

Comment: Guess. Isn't simply an equivalent to "User process" (since the User is a student)?

Answer (score 6):

My best guess: a student process is a process run by a student.

All users have to log in. The OS may well know various types of users, and may be able to determine from some table that a given user is a student. This can be useful to lower their priority for computer time in a shared machine used mainly for research, or possibly do the opposite during exam period. So having a scheduling queue for student processes would make sense.

As far as I know ... there is no direct relation to learning machines who would run processes that are studying something. But who knows? It may be coming.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what student processes are all about. what i know is that , they are just one of  the category  of process  in multilevel queue scheduling